# Can I start multiple iOS simulators simultaneously?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode now supports multiple simulators, which is great for simultaneously testing different devices. However, I still have to manually choose each device type and start the simulator.

Is there a way (e.g. using AppleScript) to easily start a set of device simulators with a given target?

Answer (score 4):

In older version of XCode you could start more than one simulator by shell with:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
>   -CurrentDeviceUDID

Now you can use simctl from command line like this:

```
xcrun simctl launch <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> <BUNDLE-ID-OF-APP-BUNDLE>
```

With the list command you can see a detailed list of available device with id:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

And for a list of available commands you can use help:

```
xcrun simctl help
```

Now you can simply create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

iPhone5iOS9="9990F41C-5580-4FEB-BB34-BC045B058134"
iPhone5siOS10="E0833485-19B3-4ABD-9A81-285473612C20"

echo "Start simulator"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator &

echo "Start iPhone 5 iOS 9.1"
xcrun simctl boot $iPhone5iOS9

echo "Start iPhone 5 iOS 10.2"
xcrun simctl boot $iPhone5siOS10
```

Do not remember to change file permission after create the script.

Comment: You don't have to launch Simulator.app either. In fact if you hold down Command when quitting or Control when closing a Simulator window, you'll be prompted on whether you want to shut down those simulators or just disconnect from them. There is also a checkbox to make that setting the default in the future.